# Unable to connect to a Linux-based SQL Server 2017 Latest database container with SSMS

Tags: docker, sql-server-2017-express

A RESTFUL API depends on a SQL Server database so I am trying to use a SQL Server Linux container as shown here.

API app dependents on a database (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu), so I ran this docker command in Windows PowerShell:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=yourpssword" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" --name sql1
-p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
```

Linux -DB Container is created successfully and running as below by Docker ps -a in Windows PowerShell
https://uploads.disquscdn.com/images/9221f417a654aca4ec2fe923ca3743c6f447772bd8b853583fe2312ea012aef2.jpg

But when I tried to connect to the newly created database container with SSMS, I get this error:

https://uploads.disquscdn.com/images/8c09b0d4c863769f4c810d2a167ce17cc2227a7e63b57a58504d5159a6eb614a.jpg

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

Please help - am I missing something else?

Thanks,

Comment: Try with Servername: `localhost, 1433` and update the SSMS

Comment: Thanks for Replay, @Max. 
I tried with COntainer Ip , port with SSMS but not working.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time, i found out below web page, it helps me to resolve the above problems..
*https://tomssl.com/running-microsoft-sql-server-on-a-linux-container-in-docker/*

I am using Windows 10 pro and docker host for development envr. For connecting sql-db
Linux based container with SSMS tool, we Need to change  docker DB port so we delete the existing container and again recreate sql-db container as below and  run command at power-shell

docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd2019'  -e 'MSSQL_PID=Developer' **-p 1401:1433** --name sql2017  -d  microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

Now i am able to connect to docker sql DB by SSMS as below
[image]

Thanks,